# Run cudamat Makefile.win on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, cuda, makefile

I used the cmd for Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 to run this make file:

```
cudamat: cudamat.cu cudamat.cuh cudamat_kernels.cu cudamat_kernels.cuh learn.cu learn_kernels.cu learn_kernels.cuh
nvcc -O --ptxas-options=-v -o libcudamat.dll --shared cudamat.cu cudamat_kernels.cu -lcublas
nvcc -O --ptxas-options=-v -o libcudalearn.dll --shared learn.cu learn_kernels.cu -lcublas

clean:
rm *.linkinfo *.pyc *.so
```

using command `nmake -f Makefile.win` from inside the cudamat directory, but i got this:

```
Makefile.win(2) : fatal error U1036: syntax error : too many names to left of '='
```

Comment: try changing each nvcc line to use `--ptxas-options -v` instead of `--ptxas-options=-v` i.e. replace the `=` with a space.

Comment: now i got This: Makefile.win(3) : fatal error U1034: syntax error : separator missing